# Can multiple lists be treated as fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, I am using a list inside another list. As of now, even if I implemented the Asynctask, my app is quite slow. Thus, I decided to use loaders. As I've multiple lists, I was thinking of implementing fragments, that is a fragment inside another fragment. Is that possible? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a list inside another list

You cannot put a `ListView` inside a `ListView` reliably. You cannot put any scrollable item inside another scrollable item (where they scroll in the same direction) reliably, at least not without a lot of work.

> a fragment inside another fragment. Is that possible?

No.

Comment: Does Commonware have any loader implementation?

Comment: @Hiccup: My [LoaderEx project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) has loaders for SQLite databases and `ShardPreferences`.

Comment: Thank you! I must congratulate you. If I even learned anything on Android, it would be from the code that you have done. Any books that you recommend that I should read to improve?

Comment: @Hiccup: "I must congratulate you. If I even learned anything on Android, it would be from the code that you have done." -- thanks! "Any books that you recommend that I should read to improve?" -- well, I am partial to the ones on [the CommonsWare site](http://commonsware.com), since I wrote them. :-)